# Markov Chains, Assistance will be much appreciated!

Tags: markov-chains

1) In the Markov chain linked below, in the long run, what fraction of the time does the chain spend in state 3?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tntbj.png

2) Find the probabilities of states  1 ,  2 , and  4  in the stationary distribution of the Markov chain  's' linked below. The label to the left of an arrow gives the corresponding transition probability.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXqdQ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $P = \begin{pmatrix} 
0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 \\
0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0.3
\end{pmatrix}$

So the long run fraction corresponds to the probability distribution $\pi$ such that: $P^T \pi = \pi $. So we need to find eigenvector of $P^T$ corresponding to eigenvalue = 1. Such eigenvector is $\pi = (0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)$ (One can check this by checking that $P^T \pi = \pi$). So in the long run 25 percent of time chain spends in state 3.

2)

$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 \\
0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\
0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.8
\end{pmatrix}$

For this porblem stationary distribution (eigenvector for eigenvalue = 1) is $\pi = (0.04761905, 0.0952381 , 0.0952381 , 0.19047619, 0.19047619,
       0.19047619, 0.19047619) \ $ (Computed numerically)

Comment: No, 1/4 of the time equals 25% of the time, not 0.25%!

Comment: corrected this .